# Radeon VII and Ubuntu problems

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

PC Specs:

```
CPU: Ryzen 7 2700x
GPU: Radeon VII
MB: ASUS X470-I
Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a single 500GB SSD
```

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, booting into it I had a black screen with a blinking line, fixed it after messing with what manager I was using, it was a little confusing so I don't know if I'm running gmd3 or lightdm.

After that, I have a login loop with everything except Wayland, which lets me log in. Once in the resolution is completely wrong as well as sever ghosting (windows would stay in place after I move them, and their details like text and buttons would punch through the old fake window), though switching the kernel from 4.18 to 4.20 fixed the resolution and ghosting.

I placed these(some website that had vega20 bins, lost the site since I'm on my phone now) files into my amdgpu folder in /lib/firmware/amdgpu with a command in terminal and nothing changed after restarting.

I tried installing AMDGPU Pro drivers from AMDs website and it says dkms failed, when I try to install dkms it's already installed.

I downloaded drivers from Obaif and Padoka PPAs but it didn't change anything.
and I have no options for driver selection in the software app.

What do I do? I can't find any information on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently running a Radeon VII on ubuntu 18.04.
Using kernel 4.15.0-47-generic and amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072.
Try this:
Install kernel 4.15.0-47-generic

```
sudo apt-get install \
linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic \
linux-modules-4.15.0-47-generic\
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic \
linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic
sudo update-grub
```

Then download amdgpu-pro 18.50 from http://amd.com

```
wget --referer support.amd.com \
https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz 
tar xf amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04
./amdgpu-pro-install
```

Add `amdgpu.dc=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`
run `sudo update-grub` and reboot into kernel 4.15.0-47-generic.

And Voilà
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results, and posted a very similar question. AMDGPU Pro drivers from AMD didn't help. VGA20 files in lib/firmware/amdgpu didn't help. Padoka PPA didn't help. Kernels 4.20 and 5.0 didn't help.

But I made some headway with Dual boot. I got them to install and coexist (on two separate SSDs) by re-installing both Win 10 and Kubuntu 18.04 in BIOS mode.  To do that, I had to use RUFUS (in windows) to burn the install images to the USB drives. Rufus has an option to create a hybrid bios/Uefi drive. Then when booting it, you need to press F12 (or whatever your mobo requires) to select the BIOS version of the drive.

Since then, I flashed the Radeon vbios to 106 and checked to see if it fixed anything. No cigar.

I think it's a UEFI firmware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update.

I found these instructions. The author deals with an RX590, but the process is almost identical.

Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK5ra2eed7w
Written version: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/rx590-ubuntu-18-04-setup-guide/137521

Here’s what I ended up doing.

Install UKUU, (ubuntu kernel update utility) which makes kernel installation really easy. 
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Using UKUU, Install kernel 4.20 or later. (I used 5.0.2)

Caution: If you reboot at this point, the new kernel will give you a black screen when you try to log in. To get around that you need to temporarily add the kernel boot parameter 'nomodeset' into grub. To do that, you press 'e' when the boot options come up. That puts you into grub's edit mode.  Add ‘nomodeset’ right after the ‘quiet’ or ‘splash’ term. Press F10 to exit and continue booting. 
[How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Download the Radeon VII Vega 20 firmware blobs. 
https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/vg20/

Put the firmware files in the /lib/firmware/amdgpu folder.

Update initramfs. 'sudo update-initramfs -k all -u'

Reboot. You shouldn’t need ‘nomodeset’ to get back in at this point.

Check to see what firmware has been loaded.
'dmesg |grep firmware' or ‘dmesg |grep vega’ or ‘dmesg |grep amdgpu’

I got an error message “Direct firmware load for amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin failed with error -2". But there is no such file on the firmware download site. It will probably be fixed later.

This allows me to run a large (150 mods) Minecraft modpack at 30+FPS, instead of 1 fps. That's at moderate graphic setting. The performance is about the same in Win 10.  OpenGL is still at 18.2.2. I have not updated via Padoka or Obaif.